# Calculating UTF8 readpos

Tags: vb.net, utf-8

Well, actually I use this in my code:

```
Public Sub WriteString(ByVal Input As String)
    Buff.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Input.Length))
    Buff.AddRange(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Input))
End Sub
Public Function ReadString(Optional ByVal Peek As Boolean = True) As String
    Dim Len As Integer = ReadInteger(True) * 2
    Dim ret As String = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Buff.ToArray, readpos, Len)
    If Peek And Buff.Count > readpos Then
        If ret.Length > 0 Then
            readpos += Len
        End If
    End If
    Return ret
End Function
```

Function ReadInteger:

```
Public Function ReadInteger(Optional ByVal peek As Boolean = True) As Integer
    If Buff.Count > readpos Then 'check to see if this passes the byte count
        Dim ret As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(Buff.ToArray, readpos)
        If peek And Buff.Count > readpos Then
            readpos += 4
        End If
        Return ret
    Else
        Throw New Exception("Byte Buffer Past Limit!") 'past byte count throw a new exception
    End If
End Function
```

I want to change Unicode to UTF8, anyone have tips or a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should strongly consider BinaryReader/Writer.

But if you're stuck with this then solve your problem by writing the number of *bytes*, not the length of the string:

```
Public Sub WriteString(ByVal Input As String)
    Dim bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Input)
    Buff.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(bytes.Length))
    Buff.AddRange(bytes)
End Sub

Public Function ReadString(Optional ByVal Peek As Boolean = True) As String
    Dim bytes = ReadInteger(True)
    Dim str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Buff.ToArray, readpos, bytes)
    readpos += bytes
    Return str
End Function
```

Do note that Buff.ToArray is ugly, it creates too much garbage.  No idea with Buff might be, if it is a MemoryStream then use GetBuffer() instead.